# How to make a where clause where the value is an array from a previous sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a small list of data which is from an SQL database and uses `mysql_fetch_array($query_run)` to get it. This all works fine and I can `echo` out that data to double check it.

But where I want to use it is another SQL query, but where it doesn't equal it. My code at the moment only doesn't include one of the data items. So, I'm guessing you have to do something to let it know it's an array not just one piece of data?

Here's my code:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM myFriends WHERE idPerson = '$loggedInUserId'";
$query_run = mysql_query($query); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
$idfriend = $row['idFriend'];       
$queryFrirend = "SELECT * FROM perosn WHERE idPerson != '$idfriend'
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: Did you search before asking this question?

Comment: yes.. there was talks on using in but you cant use !in.. or at least I have tried and it didnt work.

Comment: First of all: you forgot a " mark at the end of the last line.

Comment: you can't directly use php arrays in a query. php has to generate a **STRING** that contains sql. That means converting an array of values into a string that make sense for where/how those values will be used in the query. Plus, your code is not generating an array of values. you're pulling in arrays of row rules, then extracting ONE value and continually overwriting it.

Comment: Sidenote: Missing semi-colon and double quote in `$queryFrirend = "SELECT * FROM perosn WHERE idPerson != '$idfriend'` and closing brace `}`

Comment: This question should be downgraded. It's and old, very old question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't bother with turning an array into a WHERE clause, if the set is returned from a MySQL query.  Relational databases are built for this kind of thing.

A query with the familiar anti-join pattern will return the specified result:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM person p
  LEFT
  JOIN myFriends f
    ON f.idFriend = p.idPerson
   AND f.idPerson = '$loggedInUserId'
 WHERE f.idFriend IS NULL
```

This says get all rows from the `person` table, and match to rows from the `myFriends` table. The `WHERE` clause says to exclude rows where a matching row was found, leaving only rows from person that didn't have a matching row returned from `myFriends`. With appropriate indexes, MySQL can blaze through that, without the overhead of sending a list of id values in a WHERE clause.

But, that doesn't really answer the question you asked.

The SQL you specified, including a list of idPerson values to be excluded, can be of several forms:

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM person p
 WHERE p.idPerson NOT IN (2,3,5,7,11,13,15,17,19)
```

or

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM person p
 WHERE p.idPerson <> 2 
   AND p.idPerson <> 3
   AND p.idPerson <> 5
   AND p.idPerson <> 7
   AND p.idPerson <> 11 
   AND p.idPerson <> 13
   AND p.idPerson <> 15
   AND p.idPerson <> 17
```

or

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM person p
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
       ( SELECT 1
           FROM ( SELECT 2 AS idPerson
                  UNION ALL SELECT 3
                  UNION ALL SELECT 5
                  UNION ALL SELECT 7
                  UNION ALL SELECT 9
                  UNION ALL SELECT 11
                  UNION ALL SELECT 13
                  UNION ALL SELECT 15
                  UNION ALL SELECT 17
                  UNION ALL SELECT 19
                ) f
          WHERE f.idPerson = p.idPerson
       )
```

or

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM person p
  LEFT
  JOIN ( SELECT 2 AS idPerson
         UNION ALL SELECT 3
         UNION ALL SELECT 5
         UNION ALL SELECT 7
         UNION ALL SELECT 9
         UNION ALL SELECT 11
         UNION ALL SELECT 13
         UNION ALL SELECT 15
         UNION ALL SELECT 17
         UNION ALL SELECT 19
       ) f
    ON f.idPerson = p.idPerson
 WHERE f.idPerson IS NULL
```

---

It's just a matter of looping through the rows in the result set, and using that value to format an appropriate SQL statement. The easiest approach (apart from aforementioned avoidance of having to run two separate queries to get the resultset you want), would be to build an array of the `friendId` column values. And then turn that array into a string of comma separated literals  `2,3,5,7,9,11,13,17,19`.  Of course, you'd need to handle the edge case of no rows returned, because `foo NOT IN ()` isn't valid SQL syntax.

If you want to build the statement on the fly, as you loop through the rows, you could do something like this:

```
  $queryFrirend = "SELECT * FROM person WHERE 1=1";
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_run)) {
    $queryFrirend .= " AND idPerson <> " . (int) $row['idFriend'];
  }
  $queryFrirend .= " ORDER BY idPerson";
  echo "SQL=", $queryFrirend;
```

Though that's going to some ugly SQL. (I don't want to be around when the DBA comes hunting for you.)

Comment: WOW thanks for such a detailed response.. As you could probably guess I'm not the best coder so some of this has gone over my head.. Can I ask what <> does? and the 1=1? and what does $query_run = what my original query run was?

Comment: THE "`<>`" is the inequality operator, returns `a <> b` returns TRUE when a and b are not null and are not equal to each other.  The "`WHERE 1=1`" will always return TRUE, it doesn't do anything in the statement. If we were to string together a bunch of `"AND x"` predicates into a SQL statement, the first predicate needs to be "`WHERE x`", after that, they will be "`AND x`". We can simplify the code and avoid the special handling of the first predicate by  including an "empty" predicate in the statement. So all of the predicates we add can be "`AND x`".

Answer (score -2):

You can't use arrays in SQL queries. You need to turn the array into a String of values separated by commas, and use IN().

```
SELECT * FROM perosn WHERE idPerson Not IN ('person1', 'person2')
```

Comment: thank you for your advise! the list of people ('person1', 'person2.') will change though.. can I put it as a variable. like Not IN ($idPerson) ?

Comment: Yes. But you need to transform your array into a string that contains a list and then put it in $idPerson

Comment: So I added $newarray = implode(", ", $idfriendly); But that didnt seem to do the trick. Am I close?